# balanced structure of correlative conjunction

Tags: correlating-conjunctions, correlative-constructions

I am doubtful to decide whether the follwing sentences will be in accordance with "the balanced rule" of correlative conjunction.

> 1.Either tell the truth or you will go to jall.
>
> 2.He not only loves but also leads his children.
>
> 3.Computers are both a useful and essential device.

Comment: Well, 3 breaks the rule about conserving number.

Comment: I am neither native speaker nor a teacher but as far as I know, your first sentence grammatically wrong. Because if you use "either" before a verb, then you should use "or" before a verb too. So strictly speaking, the rule is they (either /or) both must  follow the same kind of word such as noun, adjective or verb. Therefore , I would rephrase your sentence as : " Either tell the truth or go to jail."  or another sentence could be " You could choose either Xbox or Playstation"..

Comment: @Mrt Im non-native too and I agree with that too. *tell the truth* and *you will go to jail* are not balance.

Answer (score 2):

(1) If the sentence is supposed to be a warning/threat, then you don't need "either" here. It should be:

> Tell the truth or you will go to jail.

If presenting someone with a choice, you would omit "you" instead:

> Either tell the truth or go to jail.

(2) is grammatically correct but sounds rather verbose. Better wording might be:

> He both loves and leads his children.

(3) is ungrammatical because "computers" is plural but "device" is singular. The numbers should match. The "both" is also superfluous and can be omitted:

> Computers are useful and essential devices.

or

> A computer is a useful and essential device.

Comment: Will it be right if I change "Either you tell the truth or you will go to jail"?

Comment: Yes, you could say that.